# getopt error handling for multiple comma separated values

Tags: c, csv, validation, command-line, getopt

how to validate a string variable for multiple combinations of comma separated values received from command line for getopt?

```
       case 'a' :
                    flaga=1;
                    alg = optarg;
                    printf("you entered option -a \"%s\"\n", optarg);

                    if(strcmp(alg,"lr") == 0 )
                       {
                         ....//valid
                       }
                    else if(strcmp(alg,"lda") == 0 )
                       {
                         ....//valid
                       }
                    else if(strcmp(alg,"knn") == 0 )
                       {
                          ...//valid
                       }
                     """""
                      """"
                    else
                      {
                       printf("wrong value entered for option -a \n");
                       exit();
                       }
```

option -a can accept these values : "knn","lda","lr","kart","nb","svm" .

The above code handles errors perfectly if user passes only single value .

But option -a can accept multiple values as comma separated ,

```
                    Eg :   -a knn,lr,lda
```

User can pass these values in any combination of any values !!

```
                    Eg :   -a knn,lr,lda
                    Eg :   -a knn,lda.lr
                    Eg :   -a lda,lr
```

How to check if user has passed valid values for option -a ?

The above code i have written is included in switch case and can handle if only single value for option -a is passed .

Comment: you can check if the argument after `-a` contains any combination of your valid values, but this will only work if there's no whitespace between the commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the `strtok()` function:

```
char *token;

token = strtok(optarg, ",");
while (token != NULL)
{
    if (!strcmp(token, "knn") && !strcmp(token, "lr") && !strcmp(token, "la")
        *error handling*
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

PS: `strtok()` is part of `string.h`

EDIT: I don't think this code will have your desired behaviour. This will be better:

```
char *token;
size_t i = 0;
char knn = 0, lr = 0, la = 0;

token = strtok(optarg, ",");
while (token != NULL)
{
    if (!strcmp(token, "knn") && knn == 0)
        knn = 1;
        ... // valid
    else if (!strcmp(token, "lr") && lr == 0)
        lr = 1;
        ... // valid
    else if (!strcmp(token, "la") && la == 0)
        la = 1;
        ... // valid
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong value entered for option -a\n");
        exit();
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    i++;
}

if (i > 3)
{
    printf("Too many values entered for option -a\n");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you allow several options that are separated with a comma, you must split the string at the commas and process every token. One way to split strings is the library funtion `strtok` from `<string.h>`. Take care to remove whitespace from the tokens when you compare them.

Another question is how you want to represent the result. One way is to fill an initially zeroes out array of options with ones as appropriate. Another way is to use a bit-combination so that options 0,1 and 3 correspond to 2⁰ + 2¹ + 2³ = 1 + 2 + 8 = 11. That's the method I used below.

The example program below provides a function `multi_opt` that parses a list of options that are separated by commas. When an unknown option is dound, the program exits immediately. You may opt to return an invalid bit cobination instead and pass the responsibility of error handling to the calling code.

The function also works when the argument string is empty, in which case no options are set. The `main` function shows how to use that function..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*
 *      Return index of str in opt or -1 if it can't be found.
 */
int find_opt(const char *str, const char **opt)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; opt[i];i++) {
        if (strcmp(str, opt[i]) == 0) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

/*
 *      Return a bit combination of the options from opt found in str.
 */
unsigned int multi_opt(const char *str, const char **opt)
{
    unsigned int res = 0u;
    char buf[strlen(str) + 1];
    char *p = buf;

    // copy to modifiable buffer and strip whitespace
    while (*str) {
        if (!isspace((unsigned char) *str)) *p++ = *str;
        str++;
    }

    *p= '\0';

    // split string and process tokens
    p = strtok(buf, ",");
    while (p) {
        int i = find_opt(p, opt);

        if (i < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option %s\n", p);
            exit(1);
        }

        res |= (1u << i);

        p = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    const char *opt[] = {
        "knn", "lda", "lr", "kart", "nb", "svm", NULL
    };
    char *msg = " knn, lda, svm ";
    unsigned int u;
    int i;

    u = multi_opt(msg,opt);

    for (i = 0; opt[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s: %s\n", opt[i], (u & 1u << i) ? "on" : "off");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          char *alg,alg1;

       case 'a' :
                 flaga=1;
                 alg = optarg;
                 printf("1. you entered option -a \"%s\"\n", alg);
```

This printf o/p :1. you entered option -a "svm,lr"

```
                 alg1 = strtok(optarg, ",");
                 while (alg1 != NULL)
                     {
                      if(strcmp(alg1,"lr") == 0 )
                           {
                              //valid
                            }
                         '""""""
                         '"""""""
                      else
                          {
                          }
                      alg1 = strtok(NULL, ",");
                      j++;
                   }
                 printf("2.you entered option -a \"%s\"\n", alg);
```

This printf o/p :2. you entered option -a "svm"
But expected : svm,lr

Comment: Try replacing `alg = optarg` with `alg = strdup(optarg)`: `alg` will then be a copy of `optarg`

Comment: @Silveris  Hey its working now , But whats the difference ? for same reason i declared alg and copied optarg , then used alg1 with strtok .

Comment: A `char *` is in fact a pointer to the first element of a string (the first character of the string) and this is why you need your string to end with `\0`. The `*` is to say it is a pointer. Doing `alg = optarg` will make `alg` pointing to the first element of `optarg`, you don't actually copy the string but the pointer. So if you modify something using `optarg` it will also modify it for `alg` (which is what is happening with `strtok(optarg, ",")`. This is why you need to use `strdup()` that makes a copy of the string and returns a pointer to this copy.

Comment: @Silveris  Thanks a lot for all information . Is there any option for staying connected with you here ? like add you as a friend ?

Comment: You're welcome! No you can't, Stack Overflow don't want to create this function because they don't want to do social networking. But don't hesitate to tag me in a comment if you need my help!

Comment: @Silveris     need help here please    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279658/error-while-using-machine-learning-algorith