# getopt error handling for integer values and negative values

Tags: c, validation, command-line, getopt

How to verify if the user has passed only integer value to a getopt option from the command line ? User should pass only positive integer values .

Isdigit() function does not work properly here .

```
                case 's' :
                    flags=1;

                    start = atoi(optarg);
```

How to check if start contains only integer value ?

```
                ./prog -scf
```

By default its taking s value as 0 when any character is entered  , since i am using atoi function  but here actually it should give error as cf is passed .

Even tried strtol() , but no use

```
            start = (int) strtol(optarg, &ptr, 10);
```

even if i use strtol() function , it works only if both number and strings are passed .

```
            eg ./prog -s5abc        --> this works

            eg  ./prog -sabc         -->does not work
```

here again start takes 0 value , as only charters is passed !  but if user itself passes 0 then how can i handle error ?

```
           eg ./prog -s0        --> s takes 0 value, valid

           eg  ./prog -sabc     --> s takes 0 value , but invalid
```

Comment: `if (start < 0) { ... };` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*does not work properly*"?

Comment: See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [atoi — how to identify the difference between zero and error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871711/atoi-how-to-identify-the-difference-between-zero-and-error)

Comment: Try looking into `optarg` to see if it only contains numeric characters?

Comment: @Silveris thats my question how do i do that ? isdigit() , atoi , strtol ,  none of this functions gives proper error if only characters have been passed .

Comment: What does `isdigit` return when you pass a non-digit character? In which way does this not work?

Comment: @Gerhardh    isdigit returns o for both char or digit here , since am not using unsigned values .  It works only for unsigned type !

Comment: And you cannot simply check for one single `'-'` at first position and use `isdigit` for following characters?

Comment: BTW: I doubt, that `isdigit` returns `0` for characters that are digits.

Comment: @Silveris   The code works perfect !    In the for loop ,  optarg[i] != 0    Can you explain this condition please ?

Comment: @Silveris     Is there any simple solution for this question ?                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846090/getopt-error-handling-for-multiple-comma-seprated-values/43846698#43846698

Comment: A string always ends with the character `'\0'` and its value in ASCII is `0`. For example the string `abc` is in fact `abc\0`, so you have to loop until you reached the end of the string: `\0`.

Comment: @Silveris exactly but for string "009" , How is it working ? , First only it encounters 0 right .

Comment: @programmer If it is a string it will be `"009\0"` too. Because in C strings are arrays of `char`, and '0' is not the same than 0, '0' is the ASCII value of 0 (the value stocked in a char to write 0) which in fact is 48. If you try this: `printf("%d - %d\n, '0', 0);` it will display `48 - 0`.

Comment: @programmer I answered your other question two, hope it helped :)

Comment: @Silveris  Can you explain this line of code :  token = strtok(NULL,",");            without this line loop goes infinitely , but why ?

Comment: @Silveris thank you so much both the codes are working fine , but for the other answer : ./prog -a knn,knn,knn       this should give error but it wont , only once the value can be given , for this what can we do ?

Comment: @programmer `token = strtok(NULL, ",");` prevents from infinite loops because passing `NULL` to `strtok()` means you want the next token on the string you passed first. In this case `optarg`. I also edited my answer to show you how to get an error in the case you showed me.

Comment: @Silveris now am getting error , am going need this value as it is ,  -a knn ,svm,lr     but after error checking it contains null value .

Comment: @Silveris Check out the other post i have mentioned my output , am still trying your previous code , it was working fine but when i implemented it completely its giving error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working with signed numbers, this should do:

```
if (optarg[0] != '-' && (optarg[0] < '0' || optarg[0] > '9'))
    *error handling*
for (size_t i = 1; optarg[i] != 0; i++)
    if (optarg[i] < '0' || optarg[i] > '9')
        *error handling*
```